# Struggling to understand this recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am learning about recurssion in JavaScript but struggling to get my head around this code:

```
function fac(n) {
if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return fac(n - 1) * n; //bit am having difficulty understanding
}
console.log(fac(5));
```

I can understand this fine:

```
var countdown = function(n){
    if (n>-1){
        console.log(n);
        countdown(n-1);
    } 
}
```

I understand the mathematical concept of factorial.

Comment: Please respond to the answers provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you know what a factorial is. This function will output the factorial of a number specified as an argument for `fac(n)`.

For example if you input 3, then after the first iteration you end up with

```
3 * fac(3-1)
```

after the second you'll have

```
3 * 2 * fac(2-1)
```

then

```
3 * 2 * 1 * fac(0)
```

and if n==0 you just do times one you finally end with

```
3 * 2 * 1 * 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step-by-step of how the recursion runs :

```
fac(5) = fac(4) * 5
fac(4) = fac(3) * 4
fac(3) = fac(2) * 3
fac(2) = fac(1) * 2
fac(1) = fac(0) * 1
fac(0) = 1
```

so... now all together...

```
fac(5) = 1 * 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

From Wikipedia:

> In mathematics and computer science, a class of objects or methods exhibit recursive behavior when they can be defined by two properties:
>
> - A simple base case (or cases)
> - A set of rules that reduce all other cases toward the base case

### Base Case

The base case here is 0!

```
if (n == 0)
    return 1;
```

because 0! ==1

### Rule to deduce all cases

The rule to reduce all cases toward the base case is this mathematical rule:

n!=n*(n-1)!

which is in your code

```
else
    return fac(n - 1) * n;
```